# Associate button press with table row Flask/Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, button

I have this in index.html:

```
            {% for item in data %}
            <tr>
            <td>{{item[0]}}</td>
            <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
            <td>{{item[2]}}</td>
            <td>{{item[3]}}</td>
            <td>{{item[4]}}</td>
            <td>{{item[5]}}</td>
            <td>{{item[6]}}</td>
            <td>{{item[7]}}</td>
            <td>{{item[8]}}</td>
            <td>{{item[9]}}</td>
            <td>{{item[10]}}</td>
            <td>
                    <form action="{{ url_for('history') }}" method="POST">
                    <button type="submit"> History </button>
                    </form>
            </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

And this in app.py:

```
@app.route('/history', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def history():

    return render_template('history.html')
```

So my webpage has a table with a bunch of rows and each row as a button labeled 'History'. Since right now each button does the same thing and points to history(), how can i distinguish which row of data the original click came from?

Comment: Why not just create select field in form ? With tables, you repeat almost same code multiple times. Form is for passing data to server, tables are just for representing something in tabular order...

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to add the item ID into the HTML form, but you can not display it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden

Something like the following

```
<form action="{{ url_for('history') }}" method="POST">
    <input id="historicalId" name="historicalId" type="hidden" value="{{item.id}}">
    <button type="submit"> History </button>
</form>
```

Then in flask, you'll need to parse out the request form body

Answer (score 2):

I am writing this answer as it may help someone hopefully.
Check the every table row is displaying a book and there is an edit button at the end of the table row.

```
           {% for book in books %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ book[1] }}</td>
                <td>{{ book[2] }} </td>
                <td>{{ book[3] }} </td>
                <td>{{ book[4] }} </td>
                <input id="book_id" name="book_id"
                       type="hidden" value="{{ book[0] }}">
                <td><button type="submit" name="edit" value="{{ book[0] }}"
                            formmethod="post">Edit</button></td>
            </tr>
```

Every row has a hidden book_id which is used to retrieve the book in the backend using the below code:

```
        if request.form.get("edit"):
        print('Book ID: ', request.form.get('edit'))
```